# High sum of fractional parts

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Let $n\geq 2$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n > 0$ be such that $x_1+\cdots+x_n =1$. Is it true that there must exist a positive integer $k$ such that $$\{x_1k\}+\cdots+\{x_nk\} = n-1?$$

This looks closely related to the [density of the fractional part](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903142/for-an-irrational-number-a-the-fractional-part-of-na-for-n-in-mathbb-n-is). 
Note that the quantity $\{x_1k\}+\cdots+\{x_nk\}$ is always an integer, since it equals $k-\lfloor x_1k\rfloor - \dots - \lfloor x_nk\rfloor$. Also, as each term is strictly less than one, $n-1$ is the highest value the sum can take.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the $x_i$ are rational, take the lcm of the denominators  and decrease it by $1$.

If they are not necessarily rational, act similarly: using, e.g., [Kronecker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem), take a $k$ such that all the $kx_i$ are sufficiently close to integers, and decrease that $k$ by $1$.

Comment: I've put a reference, although it is an overkill: one may merely use the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: ... another way of saying it is that the curve $t\mapsto (tx_1,\ldots ,tx_n)$ is dense in the torus $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$, thus becomes as close as you want to $0$ for some $t>0$.

Comment: @abx: this is incorrect as soon as $1,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb Q$. That's why Kronecker's theorem at my reference looks a bit... involved. In our case, they are dependent, as the $x_i$ sum up to $1$!

Comment: Oh, right of course. Still the curve is dense in some nontrivial subtorus (if at least one of the $x_i$ is irrational). But that makes the proof a bit complicated.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov what does "as soon as" mean?

Comment: You may replace it with "whenever". But, in fact, in that concrete case it is "iff".